# cyclic group definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

i would like to clarify some things related to group theory,for example let us consider two group,one with modulo $3$ and second  with modulo $2$,so we have

$G_3=(0,1,2)$  and $h_2=(0,1)$

now if i consider  sum of this group,for example let us take  some elements

$(0,1)+(1,2)$

i should know  with modulo is taken first and which second ?i was watching Youtube  video  and professor  said that

$(0,1)+(1,2)=(1,0)$

also one example

$g=(1,1)$

$g+g=(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,2)$

why it is $(0,2)$?  zero means that  $2\ ({\rm modulo}\ 2)=0$ and  $2$ means simple $2\ ({\rm modulo}\ 3)$,but how  should i understand which one is which?

Comment: You always need to specify which order you have taken the product of the groups. In this case it seems like it has been taken with mod 2 first

Comment: but second time it should  be different order?for different elements or?

Comment: Both are in the same order.

Comment: then why  is second element  $0$?

Comment: You mean in $(0,1) + (1,2)$? Because $1 + 2 = 0$ mod $3$.

Comment: You are working in $h_2 \times G_3$.

Comment: Actually, the notation for those two is awful. $G_3 = (0,1,2)$ is not the same as $G_3 = \{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: then why is $(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,2)$

Comment: $1+1 = 0 \pmod 2, \quad  1+1 = 2 \pmod 3$

Comment: For precisely the same reason. $1 + 1 = 0$ mod $2$ and $1 + 1 = 2$ mod $3$.

Comment: that is what i am asking,which order is taken first?

Comment: why not $1+1=2$ directly modulo $3$?

Comment: How does that differ from what we are saying?

Comment: If you have $(a,x),(b,y)  \in h_2\times G_3$ then 
$(a,x)+(b,y) = (a+b \mod 2, x+y \mod 3)$

Comment: aaa i   understood,so first modulo is taken from first  group and second modulo from second group

Comment: for example $G_3 *H_4$ first modulo is taken with $3$,second $4$ right?

Comment: You seem to be using some very unusual notation for those groups. Why both use $G$ and $H$? Also, it is denoted either $\oplus$ or $\times$ rather than $\ast$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the given cyclic groups:

$H = \{0, 1\},\;$ under addition modulo $2,\;$ and $\; G = \{0, 1, 2\}\;$ under addition modulo $3$.

Then $$H \times G = \{(h, g)\mid h\in H, g \in G\}, \\ \text{ And }\;(h_1, g_1) + (h_2, g_2) = \Big((h_1 + h_2) \text{ mod } 2,\;(g_1 + g_2) \text { mod } 3\Big)$$

---

Note that the order of groups in the direct sum does matter:

$$G\times H = \{(g, h)\mid g\in G, h \in H\},\\\text{ and }\;(g_1, h_1) + (g_2, h_2) = \Big((g_1 + g_2) \text{ mod } 3,\;(h_1 + h_2) \text { mod } 2\Big)$$

---

In the examples you give, it is clear that the direct sum of the groups is $H \times G$.

Note that if we have an element $(1, 1) \in H\times G$, while you name it $g$, it is NOT an element of G; it is an element in $H\times G$, represented as an ordered pair, with the first of the two entries is an element of $H$, and the second of the two entries is an element of $G$.

So $(1, 1) + (1, 1) = \Big((1 + 1) \text{ mod }2,\; (1 + 1) \text{ mod } 3\Big) = (0, 2)$.